# Close an svg path (or vector drawable)

Tags: android, svg, android-jetpack-compose, android-vectordrawable

I created a vector drawable. Now that's actually created using a third party software which converted my drawing to an svg path (which I converted to a vector drawable), but when I fill the shape, it leaks. There seem to be open gaps in between. What can I do to join these paths? I cannot place a `z` after every coordinate unless it's to the last resort.

Thanks everyone

PS: Any suggestions for programmatic approach are also welcome. For those purposes, I would like to inform that I am using Jetpack Compose.

Thanks again,

Comment: Even if you enumerate points in code(which you can easily do by retrieving path nodes from `PathParser`), how you gonna detect which is point missing? I suggest you opening your svg with an editor and adding the gaps.

Comment: You know of any editor that could do this?

Comment: Actually I think the issue is only in programmatic approach. I doubt that if I fill gradient using xml, it fills fine (I'm not sure). I'll check later. Till that, have you seen a case similar to this? I mean something in Compose might be breaking the drawable? Thanks

Comment: Figma can do this. But it needs svg, doubt it's familiar with android xml. I'm 95% sure that the problem is with svg, not with compose

Comment: Thanks again, I'll give it a try!

Comment: Yeah actually I found zero gaps in my svg (using Figma). The thing is that the software I used to convert my drawing to svg used the `polygon` tags which then I converted to android vector drawable `path`s. I did so by placing an `M` in front of each of the thirteen paths that I derived from it. Then put it all in a single path (to fill in). Then found this problem